# jquery Datatable - $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need for a specific reason to ignore jquery datatable error messages in a specific page.

when I put :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode('none')
```

I get this error :

> TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode is not a function*

I tried :

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode('none')
```

instead but same issue

How do I actually apply this setting then ?

Comment: That is supposed to be `$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is exactly what the error says, it is not a function but rather an attribute.
from [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/%24.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode), you must set it like this :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
```

Comment: You're right, that's a first step. My issue now it that jquery doesnt take this config in consideration, I still get the error I want to hide

Comment: I didn't try but as an insight, i would suggest trying to catch the error event (just like the exemple in @Nerdvoso answer) and prevent it from spreading. Something like `e.preventDefault();` if it exists. Also, you should update your question since you had gone further in your searches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you can see this from the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/event/error)

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
 
$('#example').on( 'error.dt', function ( e, settings, techNote, message ) {
    console.log( 'An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message );
}).DataTable({"ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this also and I still get my error. Is there really no way to ignore the errors from Datatable ? I get trigger anything in my document.ready because of this error

Comment: The error is not shown on loading but is still reported in the console. It is bad practice. But this I think is the best you can get.